# How old is Shisui compared to Itachi?

Tags: naruto

Before watching the recent anime arc focusing on Itachi, I had assumed that he and Shisui were roughly the same age. But in episode 452, Shisui appears as a full-fledged ninja alongside the 6 or 7-year-old Itachi when the latter was still a first-year student.

Also reading into things further, Shisui awakened his Mangekyo after witnessing an unnamed friend's death in the Third Great Ninja War, so he must have been old enough to participate there.

Is there any further information that can help nail Shisui's age down?

Comment: Unofficial [Poll about age difference between Shishu and Itachi](http://jesterry.deviantart.com/journal/poll/3579934/)

Answer (score 4):

I would like to point out; we have no idea how old Shisui was when he graduated from the Academy. At the time, the average age was nine (see Obito Uchiha and Rin Nohara). We don't know whether or not Shisui graduated early. That plays a key deciding factor here, considering he met Itachi approximately two or three years after he graduated.

If he graduated at the average wartime age, this would make him somewhere around eighteen to twenty years old at the time of his death. Thus, making him six years older than Itachi, give or take. Perhaps he graduated at six, like Kakashi, or maybe seven. Possibly eight. We have no idea. We don't know how long Shisui fought in the war for either. What if it was a year? Or more?

However, gauging his visual age 18-20 makes the most sense. In addition, have you seen the difference in height between Shisui and Itachi when they first met? There's too big a difference for there to simply be a three-year age gap, in my opinion.

Also, you need to factor in Shisui's height and weight stats from the databook. At the time of his death, he had the height and weight of an average adult male. He couldn't have been less than eighteen. I like to believe he was nineteen; six years older than Itachi.

Answer (score 1):

At the time Shisui died, he was 16 and Itachi was 12-13 years old. He met 5-year-old Itachi a year after the Third Great Ninja War. Assuming Shisui was 3 years older than Itachi, he should have been 7 during the war.

Chunin rank and above are allowed to participate in the wars. Considering Shisui was extremely talented, it makes sense that he was a Chunin at the age of 7.

Comment: That's incorrect shisui was 19 and itachi was 15

Answer (score 0):

Itachi was 12-13 and Shisui was 16.

Because Shisui died before Itachi left the village and Itachi left the village when he was 13, this means that Itachi couldn't have been 15.

This also means that if Itachi would have been 15 that the coup d'etat would've happened. Which it didn't.

Comment: Please include relevant sources/references.