# shisui the teleport age recieved jonin rank

Tags: naruto

How old was shisui when he became jonin? he looked fairly young in the itachi light and dark arc, and itachi addresses him as shisui the jonin while itachi was only a genin... he mustve been able to get jonin and chunin at a very young age

Comment: Kind of related: [How old is Shisui compared to Itachi?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/36214/how-old-is-shisui-compared-to-itachi)